# theano tutorial copy past pieces of code to try it?? where are py code files?

Tags: theano

theano tutorial is great!!
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/

but how to find .py files, since meantime I need copy past pieces of code to try it??

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial code can all be found in http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/.

These files are linked to from the tutorial pages that make use of them. For example, the [LSTM code](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/lstm.py) is linked to from the [LSTM tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html).